# WPF Load boolean values in combobox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a Combobox and I want to edit a boolean value.

```
        <dxe:ComboBoxEdit ItemsSource="{Binding EnumItemsSource}" 
                          DisplayMember="Name"
                          ValueMember="Id"
                          IsTextEditable="False"
                          EditValue="{Binding TargetValue, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

My ViewModel:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Contains the ItemsSource for Enums
    /// </summary>
    public List<EnumItemObject> EnumItemsSource
    {
        get { return _enumItemsSource; }
        set
        {
            _enumItemsSource = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

public class EnumItemObject
{
   public int Id {get;set;}
   public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

And I prepare the data for the Combobox ItemsSource that:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Sets the value to the properties for the BitTemplate view. (similar with EnumTemplate)
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="propertyInfo">a boolean property</param>
    private void PrepareDataForBitTemplate(PropertyInfo propertyInfo)
    {
        TargetValue = (int)propertyInfo.GetValue(_firstSelectedItem);
        EnumItemsSource = new List<EnumItemObject>();
        EnumItemsSource.Add(new EnumItemObject() { Id = 0, Name = "Nein" });
        EnumItemsSource.Add(new EnumItemObject() { Id = 1, Name = "Ja" });
    }
```

Is it the approach correct? Is there any easier solution?

**UPDATE:**
Extract from my ViewModel code (you remember EnumItemsSource is ItemsSource for Combobox and TargetValue the Combobox selected item):

```
    private void LookUpViewData()
    {
        var propertyInfo = _firstSelectedItem.GetType().GetProperty(TargetFieldDescription.fdBigViewColumnName);
        if ((propertyInfo != null) && (propertyInfo.GetValue(_firstSelectedItem) != null))
        {
            if ((int) FieldDataType.ENum == TargetFieldDescription.fdDataType)
                PrepareDataForEnumTemplate(propertyInfo);
            if ((int) FieldDataType.Bit == TargetFieldDescription.fdDataType)
                PrepareDataForBitTemplate(propertyInfo); // like EnumTemplate
            else if ((int) FieldDataType.Time == TargetFieldDescription.fdDataType)
                PrepareDataForTimeTemplate(propertyInfo);
            else
                PrepareDataForDefaultTemplate(propertyInfo);
        }
        else
            TargetValue = String.Empty;
    }

    private void PrepareDataForEnumTemplate(PropertyInfo propertyInfo)
    {
        TargetValue = (int)propertyInfo.GetValue(_firstSelectedItem);
        if (_targetFieldDescription.fdEnumSource != null)
        {
            switch (_targetFieldDescription.fdEnumSource)
            {
                case "Station":
                    EnumItemsSource = ConvertListToEnumItemObjectList(_targetFieldDescription.fdEnumSource);
                    break;
                default:
                    EnumItemsSource = EnumUtil.ConvertEnumToEnumItemObjectList(_targetFieldDescription.fdEnumSource);
                    break;
            }

        }
    }

    private void PrepareDataForBitTemplate(PropertyInfo propertyInfo)
    {
        var value = propertyInfo.GetValue(_firstSelectedItem);
        bool bValue;
        if (value == null)
            TargetValue = 0;
        else if (bool.TryParse(value.ToString(), out bValue))
            TargetValue = (bValue) ? 1 : 0;
        else
            TargetValue = 0;
        //TargetValue = (int)propertyInfo.GetValue(_firstSelectedItem);
        var bitItems = new List<EnumItemObject>();
        bitItems.Add(new EnumItemObject { Id = 0, Name = "Nein" });
        bitItems.Add(new EnumItemObject { Id = 1, Name = "Ja" });
        EnumItemsSource = bitItems;
    }
```

So I want to load three possible kind of data in my Combobox. Enums, List of Objects (with name and id) and booleans (Yes/No List).

Answer (score 3):

It's not clear *where* this `PrepareDataForBitTemplate(PropertyInfo)` method is located. Is it code-behind? Whatever it is, if the goal is to bind a *ComboBox* with some enum values, I would much rather keep it standard - meaning the `DataContext` of the *ComboBox* is the *ViewModel* of the containing `Window` or `UserControl`:

```
public IEnumerable<SomeEnumType> ViewModelEnumValues
{
    get { return Enum.GetValues(typeof(SomeEnumType)).Cast<SomeEnumType>(); }
}

private SomeEnumType _selectedEnumValue;
public SomeEnumType SelectedEnumValue
{
    get { return _selectedEnumValue; }
    set { _selectedEnumValue = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(() => SelectedEnumValue); }
}
```

Before I move on to the corresponding XAML markup, a few observations:

- The *ViewModel* implementation derives from some `ViewModelBase` abstract class which implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` and allows its derivatives to specify a property name in a strongly-typed way. I see your setter calls some `OnPropertyChanged()` method, but not how that method is able to notify the *View* that a *specific property* was changed.
- The name `Enum` refers to a *specific language construct*. Calling something "Enum" when that something **is not an enum** is rather confusing.
- I don't see why you're not using an actual `enum` when the values you're trying to load are basically "Yes" and "No".
- `EnumItemObject` is an awful name, for several reasons:

  1. It's not an *object*, it's a *class* - an *object* is an *instance* of a *class*.
  2. It's not an *enum item*, it's essentially a *ViewModel* that exposes two properties - an `int` and a `string`.
  3. It's not immediately apparent how this class relates to any type of enum.

Now, given that your *ViewModel* exposes the above `SelectedEnumValue` and `ViewModelEnumValues` properties (both bad/stub names), with a ValueConverter the XAML for the ComboBox would be as simple as this:

```
<ComboBox ItemSource="{Binding ViewModelEnumValues}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedEnumValue, Mode=TwoWay}">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Border Style="{StaticResource ListItemBorder}"> <!-- just some border -->
                <StackPanel>
                    <Image Source="{Binding Value, Converter={StaticResource EnumValueIconConverter}}" />
                    <Label Content="{Binding Value, Converter={StaticResource EnumValueNameConverter}}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

And the converters would look like this:

```
using resx = Project.Properties.Resources;    

public class EnumValueToStringConverter : ConverterBase
{
    public override object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        SomeEnumType result;
        return Enum.TryParse(value.ToString(), out result)
                   ? resx.ResourceManager.GetString(promoType + "Caption")
                   : string.Empty;
    }
}

public class EnumValueToIconConverter : ConverterBase
{
    public override object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var result = string.Empty;
        var typedValue = value As SomeEnumType;
        if (typedValue != null)
        {
            switch(typedValue)
            {
                case SomeEnumType.EnumValue1:
                    result = "images/image-for-value1.png";
                    break;
                case SomeEnumType.EnumValue2:
                    result = "images/image-for-value2.png";
                    break;
            }
        }

        return new BitmapImage(new Uri("/project.namespace;component/" + result, UriKind.Relative));
    }
}
```

Of course this is overkill if all you want is the enum *names* in your dropdown list - but I tend to define a `DataTemplate` for just about everything (and I think I have a tendency to abuse converters, too).

If all you need is to display an enum value directly in the UI, then this will suffice:

```
public IEnumerable<string> ViewModelEnumNames
{
    get { return Enum.GetNames(typeof(SomeEnumType)).ToList(); }
}

private string _selectedEnumName;
public string SelectedEnumName
{
    get { return _selectedEnumName; }
    set { _selectedEnumName = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(() => SelectedEnumName); }
}
```

```
<ComboBox ItemSource="{Binding ViewModelEnumNames}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedEnumName, Mode=TwoWay}">
```

Comment: Hello retailcoder, thanks for your support. Your opinion is very interesting, thanks. 

PrepareDataForBitTemplate is a function located in my ViewModel. But one question. I do an update in my post. I want to be able to load in this Combobox not only enums. Also list of Stations, list of countries, list of enumvalues, list with Yes/No.
How can I design the property public IEnumerable<SomeEnumType> ViewModelEnumValues to achieve this? Your solution is based only for enums, but my combobox should load list of objects and be able to update also boolean values. Pls take a look at my update above.

Comment: See the 2nd example; all the combobox needs is any `IEnumerable`, *how* the displayable data ends up there is irrelevant to the *view* (could be your *model*'s concern) - for full-fledged objects all you need is a data template. :)